# mysql "select" issue while trying to retrieve smallest value

Tags: php, mysql

i have in my db several rows of the below data:

```
 name    price
 iphone  1000
 iphone  888
 iphone  1010
```

i am trying to get the for the iphones the cheapest price but my script returns the most expensive one

```
class getdbdata {

    function cheapestprice($nameofproduct) {

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "username";
        $password = "password";
        $dbname = "mobilephones";
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, 
        $password);
        $sql = ("SELECT name,price  FROM phones where name like 
        '%".$nameofproduct."%' and  price =(SELECT MIN(price) FROM phones)");  
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute() ;
        $posts= $stmt->fetch() ;
            foreach ($posts as $post ) {
        echo $post;
            }
            var_dump($posts);   
    }

}

$getdbdata = new getdbdata();
$getdbdata->cheapestprice("iphone");
```

Comment: You don't need a sub-select but if you use it, you'd need to add a `WHERE` as well. Instead you can use `SELECT name, MIN(price) FROM phones WHERE name like :name GROUP BY name`.

Comment: It's about the type of your column "price" in the database... make sure it's a double or float and not a varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query to :

```
SELECT name, Min(price) FROM phones where name like '%".$nameofproduct."%'
```